# How to apply multiple search patterns with Directory.EnumerateFiles()?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I use below code for searching files in a directory(& it's sub-directories) with a specific extension:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item) + ".ext1" , SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Now, I can have file with different extensions like ".ext1",".ext2", ".ext3". I would like to combine these extensions in my search pattern something like below:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item) + ".ext1||.ext2" , SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a custom method that splits the pattern string and then calls `EnumerateFiles`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> MultiEnumerateFiles(string path, string patterns)
{
    foreach (var pattern in patterns.Split('|'))
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            yield return file;
}
```

By using `yield` you get the same lazy-evaluation behavior as with the original `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: The `yield` doesn't make it lazy. Had you done `return from pattern in patterns.Split('|') from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories) select file;` you would have gotten a lazy evaluation too.

Comment: @Enigmativity doesn't this compile to the same? `SelectMany` (that's what your code uses internally) is exactly implemented using two foreach loops and a `yield return`. I'm confused.

Comment: @Enigmativity I extra checked now. It does evaluate lazily. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y0EXnX Please research before posting. I expect more from someone owning the linq gold badge.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that `yield` itself wasn't necessary to make it lazy. I didn't mean that `yield` would mean it was eager. Sorry, just a bad choice of words. I was trying to convey that there was a way to make it lazy without using `yield`.

Comment: @Enigmativity well linq uses it under the hood. So actually yes.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, it worked for me & sorry for the late response.